# How can I make my button stay transparent when clicked?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, frontend, navbar

[white button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB1Lh.jpg)

I was trying to make a vertical navbar with a background image. But as I clicked the button, they turned to white. What steps can I take to make them stay white? Like, I've tried primary-outline stuff I searched, but it doesn't work out.

Comment: Post your code. It may help you to get solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define [pseudo classes](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) for your button, link?

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: I've tried the hover before according to someone's advise. But it didn't work out. Now that I've deleted the li and ul. It worked out. But I still don't understand why and how.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this myself. It was because there was a fault in my markup. I added  inside

. But I still don't know why this is wrong. Here's the codepen:

```
    <div class="paintallblack">
  <div class="row">
    <!--let's row this.  Like, 1 md for vertical navbar, 5 md each for the rest -->
    <div class="col-md-1 verticalnav">
      <div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <a class="btn" href="#mypic">
          A<br>b<br>o<br>u<br>t</a>
        <a class="btn" href="#">
            P<br>o<br>r<br>t<br>f<br>o<br>l<br>i<br>o</a>
        <a class="btn" href="#"> C<br>o<br>n<br>t<br>a<br>c<br>t</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1  leftcontent">
      <!--LEFT PART CONTENTS FOR ABOUT, PORT, AND CONTACT-->
      <img id="mypic" src="https://scontent-sit4-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/15940460_161286387692018_3963016562080030457_n.jpg?oh=6e79da88fff3df387121a5ac66a7de32&oe=59212A06" alt="mystupidface">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5 rightcontent">
      <!--RIGHT PART CONTENTS FOR ABOUT, PORT, AND CONTACT-->
      <p>Here I am, struggling to learn web development in order to build my own online magazine one day. Who am I? What do I do? In clear weather, I run. I can write stories, poetries, book reviews, compose musics, draw pictures. But nowadays my priorities
        are: run for my health, learn to code, and try to read and write science-fiction as frequent as I can.</p>
    </div>


  </div>
```

http://codepen.io/Hertzsprung/pen/JEKxwN.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap default style is

```
.btn-link, .btn-link:active, .btn-link:focus, .btn-link:hover {
    border-color: transparent;
}
```

Override the style btn-link border-color:#fff; not transparent
Here is

```
.btn-link, .btn-link:active, .btn-link:focus, .btn-link:hover {
    border-color: #fff;
}
```